# Nodejs "TypeError: (0 , _events.once) is not a function" when using events.once()

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

I'm having trouble getting the Nodejs events.once() function working. Node@12.18.3

Working event emitter example:

```
import { EventEmitter, once } from 'events';

async function testFunc() {
  var emitter = new EventEmitter();

  emitter.on("event", (result) => {
    console.log(result);
  })

  emitter.emit("event", 1000);    
}

testFunc();
```

Output: `1000`

Failing event emitter:

```
import { EventEmitter, once } from 'events';

async function testFunc() {
  var emitter = new EventEmitter();

  let test = await once(emitter, "event");
  console.log(test);

  emitter.emit("event", 1000);    
}

testFunc();
```

Error message: `TypeError: (0 , _events.once) is not a function`

It seems to me that it should be working fine. I can't figure out why `once()` is not a function. Any help would be much appreciated.